# Parse data from an ICS file and expose it to a liquid variable in the template

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have searched tirelessly for this on Google but unfortunately every search collides with the fact Jekyll is a site generator and the results do not help.

I'm looking for a small example of how to read an ICS file from a plugin/generator that is then accessible with liquid from the templates.

I've tried creating collections and appending to them in plugins, I've tried creating `site.data` arrays. Nothing seems to work. Is there a small example of a jekyll plugin that reads a file or url and creates data that is then stored in a site variable and can be accessed via liquid? Specifically I'll be reading an ICS feed and creating a calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data files might not be able to fulfil your requirement. You need a Jekyll Plugin.

Here's an ad-hoc solution I would implement to read `ics` files and expose calendar events to liquid variables in Jekyll:

Add [`icalendar`](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) to your `Gemfile` and install it:

```bash
bundle add icalendar
bundle install
```

Put this file in `_plugins/calendar_reader.rb`

```rb
require "jekyll"
require "icalendar"

module Jekyll
  module ICSReader
    def read_calendar(input)
      begin
        calendar_file = File.open(input)
        events = Icalendar::Event.parse(calendar_file)

        hash = {}
        counter = 0

        # loop through the events in the calendars
        # and map the values you want into a variable and then return it:

        events.each do |event|
          hash[counter] = {
            "summary" => event.summary,
            "dtstart" => event.dtstart,
            "dtend" => event.dtend,
            "description" => event.description
          }

          counter += 1
        end

        return hash
      rescue
        # Handle errors
        Jekyll.logger.error "Calendar Reader:", "An error occurred!"

        return {}
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ICSReader)
```

The [`README.md`](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar#readme) docs of `icalendar` would help you understand how data is being read from the file. Basically, we parse the events in the file and map them to a dictionary and return it.

Now take an ics file and put it into the `_data` folder.

`_data/my_calendar.ics`

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20050118T211523Z
UID:bsuidfortestabc123
DTSTART;TZID=US-Mountain:20050120T170000
DTEND;TZID=US-Mountain:20050120T184500
CLASS:PRIVATE
GEO:37.386013;-122.0829322
ORGANIZER:mailto:joebob@random.net
PRIORITY:2
SUMMARY:This is a really long summary to test the method of unfolding lines
 \, so I'm just going to make it a whole bunch of lines.
ATTACH:http://bush.sucks.org/impeach/him.rhtml
ATTACH:http://corporations-dominate.existence.net/why.rhtml
RDATE;TZID=US-Mountain:20050121T170000,20050122T170000
X-TEST-COMPONENT;QTEST="Hello, World":Shouldn't double double quotes
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20110118T211523Z
UID:uid-1234-uid-4321
DTSTART;TZID=US-Mountain:20110120T170000
DTEND;TZID=US-Mountain:20110120T184500
CLASS:PRIVATE
GEO:37.386013;-122.0829322
ORGANIZER:mailto:jmera@jmera.human
PRIORITY:2
SUMMARY:This is a very short summary.
RDATE;TZID=US-Mountain:20110121T170000,20110122T170000
END:VEVENT
```

This sample ics file is taken from the [icalendar repository](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/main/spec/fixtures/two_events.ics).

Now you can use the plugin filter from your markdown/html:

```
{% assign events = "_data/my_calendar.ics" | read_calendar %}
```

Here `read_calendar` is the function defined in `_plugins/calendar_reader.rb` and `_data/my_calendar.ics` is the file you want to get the data from. The plugin gets the `input` as `_data/my_calendar.ics`, reads it and returns a `hash` which is stored into the `events` variable itself.

You can now use `{{ events }}` to access the hash of the data that you return from the function in the plugin file.

```
// {{ events }}

{0=>{“summary”=>”This is a really long summary to test the method of unfolding lines, so I’m just going to make it a whole bunch of lines.”, “dtstart”=>#<DateTime: 2005-01-20T17:00:00+00:00 ((2453391j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “dtend”=>#<DateTime: 2005-01-20T18:45:00+00:00 ((2453391j,67500s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “description”=>nil}, 1=>{“summary”=>”This is a very short summary.”, “dtstart”=>#<DateTime: 2011-01-20T17:00:00+00:00 ((2455582j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “dtend”=>#<DateTime: 2011-01-20T18:45:00+00:00 ((2455582j,67500s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “description”=>nil}}


// {{ events[0] }}

{“summary”=>”This is a really long summary to test the method of unfolding lines, so I’m just going to make it a whole bunch of lines.”, “dtstart”=>#<DateTime: 2005-01-20T17:00:00+00:00 ((2453391j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “dtend”=>#<DateTime: 2005-01-20T18:45:00+00:00 ((2453391j,67500s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “description”=>nil} 

// {{ events[1] }}

{“summary”=>”This is a very short summary.”, “dtstart”=>#<DateTime: 2011-01-20T17:00:00+00:00 ((2455582j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “dtend”=>#<DateTime: 2011-01-20T18:45:00+00:00 ((2455582j,67500s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, “description”=>nil}
```

This was the bare-bones of how a Jekyll `Filter` works. You can dive deeper into other types of Jekyll Plugins as explained in the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/).

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I was focused on using a generator to create data and store it in the collections or data set but this works just as well.

Comment: @ChrisValentine [Jekyll Generators](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/) are types of plugins used to create site pages using custom code and directives. For example my plugin [jekyll-auto-authors](https://github.com/gouravkhunger/jekyll-auto-authors) creates automated paginated author pages for jekyll blogs by overriding `Jekyll::Generator`. In this case you wanted to read and expose data from a file, you could either use a [Filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/filters/) or a [Hook](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/hooks/). Filters are easier to implement and use.

Comment: So this does not work with the current version of Jekyll and current version of Ruby. Invalid argument error. I did some digging and everything recommended downgrading to get around the error but that did not work for me.

Comment: @ChrisValentine I updated the answer. There were 2 problems: First, we installed `icalendar` using `gem` but did not add it to `Gemfile`. Thus, Jekyll wasn't able to identify where to look for the gem. Second, the filter `read_calendar` was being used incorrectly. I have updated the answer and added an example that works for me. Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Created https://ics-reader-plugin-example.gouravkhunger.me/ and https://github.com/gouravkhunger/ics-reader-plugin-example for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is now working for me and I can see the lifecycle for the data from start to finish!! Appreciated!

Comment: Awesome, congrats!